# Reusing the bytes in a source buffer (MediaSource Extensions)

Tags: javascript, html, media-source, adaptive-bitrate

I am using MSE (MediaSource Extensions API) to append bytes to a buffer (I am implementing DASH). It seems that the source buffers provided with the MSE API do not expose the actual bytes being buffered.

So after supplying the bytes to the buffer:

```
buffer.appendBuffer(bytes);
```

If I want to reuse those bytes - I need to get them from the bytes variable. But this is a bad solution, because it means having a double memory footprint - one per the bytes variable and one per the source buffer.

It is possible to get the buffered ranges pretty easily by iterating over the ranges variable using the start and end methods:

```
var ranges = sourceBuffer.buffered;
```

Is it also possible to somehow get the actual bytes that the buffer caches so that I can reuse them?

Comment: Did you ever learn the answer to this? I'm facing the same dilemma and looking for answers.